# How to achieve such a slide theme using TeX (probably not beamer)?

Tags: beamer, templates, presentations, slideshow

I am quite impressed with the cleanness and beauty of the following slides [following slides](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/economics/14-05-intermediate-macroeconomics-spring-2013/lecture-notes/MIT14_05S13_LecNot_Ramsey.pdf), taken from the [MIT OpenCourseWare](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/economics/14-05-intermediate-macroeconomics-spring-2013/).

From the looks of it, it does not seem to use the `beamer` class at, but a rather *standard* class and changes in the page size and probably some other options.

**Maybe someone here already achieved something similar and could provide a preamble that produces some similar results, or tips on how to get something in this direction.**

[image: pretty clean slides]

Comment: [OT] Are you planning to use these as overheads in a talk? If so, please remember that slides are there to _support_  what you say: there are _far too many words_ on them. Of course, if they are handouts ...

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am not sure what was the original intent of the slides. Its from MIT open course, so it could be for people following the course online. Or, just as handouts for students... (most of the slides provided by my professors is something between slides and handout, rather on the handout side...) 

In any case, I am only after the overall **aesthetic of the theme...** (for a presentation, I would probably use a slightly bigger font and, therefore, present less info per slide...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you say, looks like you can use a standard class and change the page size (with the `geometry` package) and header/footer (with `fancyhdr`).

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\geometry{
    paperwidth=16cm,
    paperheight=12cm,
    margin=1.5cm
}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{Some Dude}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\author{Dude}
\title{Stuff}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\blinddocument
\end{document}
```